# Using Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) from .NET - best method/project available?

Tags: .net, volume-shadow-service

I'd like to add VSS support to an application I'm developing and the only good packaged method available seems to be [AlphaVSS](http://alphavss.codeplex.com/), though it hasn't been actively developed in almost two years. Are there other projects out there that I just can't find, or is there a more straightforward method to accessing the "API" (if you can call it that)?

Comment: I've been searching a lot until now, but like you the only one I've found is AlphaVSS. Unfortunately now it is quite stopped....

Comment: Development of AlphaVSS hasn't actually stopped, just moving very slowly unfortunately.  But development is progressing nevertheless.

Comment: @DeCaf - Thanks for the update - I just checked the project and saw that there's been recent activity. I suppose development never really stops - the project I'm building (and for which I asked this question) hasn't seen much activity in the last year either, but it slowly marches forward when I have time. Here's to both of us making some real progress!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use WMI [Win32_ShadowCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394428%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class. I don't have a C# sample, but working with WMI is usually nicer in PowerShell in any case:

```
function global:CREATE-SHADOW ( $Drive ) { 
  (Get-WmiObject -list win32_shadowcopy).Create($Drive,"ClientAccessible") 
}
```

via: http://www.energizedtech.com/2010/04/powershell-creation-of-a-shado.html

Comment: This is an interesting angle - thanks for proposing it! If it works well, it will be an easy cross-OS-version way to do the shadow copies, and I'll be eternally grateful.

Comment: @STLDeveloper I actually abandoned this project not long after posting this response and never got to attempt implementing this suggestion. I'll accept it as it was the only response I received, and appears to solve the problem, but I can't confirm!